# Repeated values in Elasticsearch array and query scoring

Tags: elasticsearch

I have two documents with a field `country` which can contain repeated values, e.g.

Doc1:

```
country: [US, US, GB, US]
```

Doc2:

```
country: [US, GB]
```

I need a query that when looking for `country:US` will assign a higher score to `Doc1` than `Doc2` since `US` appears multiple times in the `country` field of `Doc1`, while it will assign  the same score to the two documents when looking for `country:GB` as it appears the same number of times in both documents. Is this something achievable with Elasticsearch?

Comment: What is the type of country field in mapping?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are doing a simple match search on US

```
GET countryindex/_search
{
  "query": {
   "match": {
     "country": "US"
   }
  }
}
```

It will give more score to more frequency of elements so  [US, US, GB, US] will get more score than "[US, GB]"
If you will search for "GB" -->"[US, GB]" will get more score than [US, US, GB, US], since shorter field length gets more score.

If you want to give same score when number of matches is same , you need to give [norms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/norms.html): false in your mapping.

```
{
  "properties": {
    "title": {
      "type": "text",
      "norms": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is the match query going to work as you described even if the country field is of type `keyword`?

Comment: You can define country like  "country":{   "type": "text",    "fields": {      "keyword":{        "type":"keyword"       }        }      }. Do a match on country and exact match on country.keyword.

Comment: Following mapping will be more appropriate for your req PUT countryindex
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
       "country":{
         "type": "object",
         "properties": {
           "countryname":{
             "type":"text",
              "norms": false,
              "fields":{
                "keyword": {"type":"keyword"}
              }
           }
         }
       }
    }
  }
}

Comment: Would the wildcard query behave like the match query, i.e. giving higher score to the arrays with multiple matches? e.g. "wildcard" : { "country": "U*" }

Comment: Wildcard query by default gives constant score , you need to pass additional value "rewrite": "scoring_boolean" for score to calculate